# An object sticks out of the bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On this drawing, the dark green are distances I like and red is one I don't
[image: col lag]

Can't understrand why the donate button isn't symmetrical to center the way the logo on the left is. To paraphrase, why isn't it as far from the right edge of the screen as the logo is from the left one ?

The goal is to have both the logo and the donate button "hanging over" the content that is full width of a screen (which would be pictures only) and "on the sides" of content that is centered text (on equal small distance from it).

I'm really bad at front end and a newbie coder overall, so idk if I tried good enough but I tried playing with all the paddings and margins I could think of and it just feels like something about the columns (I mean that adding a separate style for the donate button with negative margins shouldn't be a thing, there gotta an underlying problem).

```css
/* Footer fixing */

#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 70vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: static;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  /* Footer height */
}

#card-deck {
  background-color: #78c2ad;
}

#navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#logo-fixed {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#donate_button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#glass {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.212)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>
    title
  </title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> {# Global stylesheets #}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/minty/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/FPG.css' %}">
</head>

<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
  {% wagtailuserbar %}

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  bg-white" id="navbar-fixed">

    <div class="col-1"></div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <img src="{% static 'FPG_logo.png' %}" class="mt-100 pt-100" id="logo-fixed" alt="LOGO HERE">
    </div>

    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Fellowship for Perpetual Growth (FPG)</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Our animals</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Our plants</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Needed supplies</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Volunteer</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <a href="https://www.paypal.com/us/fundraiser/112574644767835624/charity/3123091" class="btn btn-success active" id="logo-fixed" role="button" type="button">Donate</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1"></div>

  </nav>

  {% block landing %} {% endblock landing %}
  <div id="page-container">
    <div id="content-wrap">
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="mt-3">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida
          orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna felis sollicitudin mauris. Integer in mauris eu nibh euismod gravida. Duis ac tellus et risus vulputate vehicula. Donec lobortis risus a elit. Etiam
          tempor. Ut ullamcorper, ligula eu tempor congue, eros est euismod turpis, id tincidunt sapien risus a quam. Maecenas fermentum consequat mi. Donec fermentum. Pellentesque malesuada nulla a mi. Duis sapien sem, aliquet nec, commodo eget, consequat
          quis, neque. Aliquam faucibus, elit ut dictum aliquet, felis nisl adipiscing sapien, sed malesuada diam lacus eget erat. Cras mollis scelerisque nunc. Nullam arcu. Aliquam consequat. Curabitur augue lorem, dapibus quis, laoreet et, pretium ac,
          nisi. Aenean magna nisl, mollis quis, molestie eu, feugiat in, orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer" class="page-footer teal">
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md">
          <h5>More Info</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="">Our Values</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="">Latest Newsletter</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md">
          <h5>Contact Info</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
            <li><a class="text-muted">808-968-7161</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted">PO Box 565</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted">Mountain View, HI 96771</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md">
          <h5>Legal Info</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
            <li><a class="text-muted">FPG Sanctuary is a Hawai‘i Nonprofit Corporation with IRS 501(c)(3) tax code exempt status. Tax ID 82-2575477.</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1 col-md">
          <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2018</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  {# Global javascript #}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mysite.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS you can share?

Comment: Also, try adding a working, running code snippet illustrating the issue so it's easy for people to help you.

Comment: just added CSS, sorry/thanx

Comment: @RaghavHerugu what do you mean by "running code snippet", adding the rest of the html ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm late, but I mean that a code snippet you can run and compile. You can access this by editing your question, going up to the top, and clicking the little page icon with brackets. If you need help, here is a video link: https://i.imgur.com/HCICbdF.mp4 this link is a tutorial on how to do that

Comment: @RaghavHerugu Thank you for a tip, I updated it with a compile-able snippet, please take a look.

Comment: @John I added a snippet you can run here, could you please take a look ?